# Launching one MobileFirst app from another and receiving the event once its already started

Tags: javascript, cordova, android-intent, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a Cordova plugin that successfully launches one MobileFirst app from another, and in the launched application, receives data from the launching app successfully.  (Very similar to this LaunchMyApp Custom-URL-Scheme PhoneGap plugin https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/844.)

However, if my launched application is already running, and go back to the launching app and launch the app a second time, I can't figure out which javascript event to listen to to receive this updated Intent and context.

If I manually call to my Landing Context function from inside the Launched application, I do actually see my updated Intent and Data that was passed from the secondary launch.

Any ideas which MobileFirst event, or method I can listen to to detect this application's updated launch Intent?

Answer (score 1):

I found it, it's the phonegap "resume" event.

Code like this works to fire my cordova plugin to retrieve the "record launch context".

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", lang.hitch(this, this.checkLandIntent), false);
document.addEventListener("resume", lang.hitch(this, this.checkLandIntent), false);

checkLandIntent: function() {
    cordova.exec(null, null, "LaunchApp", 'land', []);
}
```